# Meteor: How do you add a module, NodeJS style?

Tags: node.js, meteor

So in Node I'm used to creating a file which exports an object or a function. In Meteor I believe that every file is parsed and any variable added there is added as global.

I want to be able to add files that are only used as required, or when I import them, and for them to not be able to assign global variables.

Or maybe I'm doing it wrong? Is there a Meteor way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 1.3, Meteor supports ES2015 modules and the `import` statement. Anything in the `imports/` folder is not eagerly loaded, and it's recommended you put pretty much everything in there and use imports.

Before 1.3, [Atmosphere packages](https://guide.meteor.com/writing-atmosphere-packages.html) were the Meteor way of doing this. You can also [use npm packages directly](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html) by adding a package.json to your project.

More info:

[Application Structure](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html)

[1.3 best practices](https://guide.meteor.com/1.3-migration.html)